# Unable to Install BeautifulSoup on Windows10, Python3.4-webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have researched this whole website on how to install beautiful soup. I have installed selenium

[image: selenium scrnshot]

I am currently trying to pull jobs which use Python, also to include the details of the job like location, i,e; job title, salary(if posted), etc.. off the internet as a final in a html table. Dont chew me up completely.. give me a little break, I am learning as I go.

I understand I need to seperate the paragraphs by

, but how to go about it, is where I am getting stuck. This is what I have so far.

```
import parser
import urllib.request
import html.entities
import selenium
import re

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://Indeed.com/').read()
tb = re.find_all('<p>')
print(sauce)
```

I get this as an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Devel/BSoup4.py", line
>   8, in 
>       table = re.find_all('
>
> ') AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: why arent you using bs4 findall method

Comment: When i use bs4, it gives me an error, no module named 'bs4'. Any ideas of how to fix this?? Thank you for the help!

Comment: you need to install bs4. You can do that through your interpreter sometimes or through `pip`  Just google pip usage and you will find a ton

Comment: Thank you! I have downloaded bs4, and I am still sifting through how to use the pip through either the shell, idle, or cmd

Comment: `pip` works well should be pretty straight forward. If you are still having problems try using PyCharm IDE. You can install modules through the gui and it is really easy. When installing bs4 take note of where your interpreter is and ensure that you are installing and using pip from them same location

Comment: Thank you Joe! I figured out how to download bs4, but now it's giving me an error that it's not the correct one, and needs to be 3 instead of 2. Now updating is what I am trying to figure out.  I have been searching through here, and I am managing pretty well. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

syntax is `re.findall()` not `find_all`

Comment: Thank you! Feedback is awesome!